# SAS Unique and Distinct- but need an additional variable as well

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset that I'm trying to get a frequency from in SAS. Essentially there are a bunch of episodes and whether someone had an event. An episode could technically have more than one event. Each record also has an organization identifier. I've developed a code (below) that correctly identifies the frequency of events per episode (so for instance, 1, 2, and 3 events per episode):

```
proc sql;
    create table out as select unique
        episode_id, sum(event) as total_event
    from table1
    group by episode_id;
quit; 

proc freq data=out;
    tables total_event;
run;
```

This code while great for giving me a quick frequency of the number of events per episode is missing a vital piece of information I need- namely the organization_id. Whenever I add organization_id to the code, the frequencies become wrong. I tried to merge back the out table to table1 to get the organization_id as well but that also adds to the frequency. How do I add an additional variable so that I can ultimately run the following frequency:

```
proc freq data=out;
tables organization_id*total_event;
run;
```

Comment: Show your code for adding organization_id.  And ideally show some example data.

Comment: Just a thought, but if `ORGANIZATION_ID` is the same for all events in an episode (which makes sense), then why can you not use `episode_id, organization_id, sum(event) as total_event` for the `SELECT` list and `group by episode_id, organization_id` as the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Organization_ID is not necessarily the same for all events in an episode. When I tried doing this method it increases the frequency amounts

Comment: Just to clarify- organization_id, and episode_id are not something that I create. The dataset that my above code creates a row with the episode_id and then a total_event of 1. The original file has a row with episode_id with the organization_id and then the event variable that can either be 0 or 1. An event of 1 means that an event occurred

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your goal, I think you need an additional merge with the data itself and then dedupe by the `ORGANIZATION_ID` to get the cross-tab you want:

```
data table1;
    length EPISODE_ID $3 EVENT 3 ORGANIZATION_ID $3;
    input EPISODE_ID $ EVENT ORGANIZATION_ID $;
    datalines;
    A   0   123
    A   1   123
    A   1   456
    B   0   123
    B   1   456
    C   1   456
    C   1   789
    C   1   789
    C   0   789
    D   0   123
    D   0   123
    D   0   123
    D   1   123
    D   1   123
    ;
run;

** sum EVENT over distinct EPISODE_ID **;
proc sql noprint;
    create table out1 as
    select a.*,b.TOTAL_EVENT
    from
        (select * from table1) a,
        (select distinct EPISODE_ID, sum(EVENT) as TOTAL_EVENT from table1 group by EPISODE_ID) b
        where a.EPISODE_ID = b.EPISODE_ID;
quit;

** dedupe by ORGANIZATION_ID **;
proc sort data = out1(keep = ORGANIZATION_ID TOTAL_EVENT) out=out2 nodupkey;
    by ORGANIZATION_ID;
run;

proc freq data=out2;
    tables ORGANIZATION_ID*TOTAL_EVENT;
run;
```

Otherwise you could try a `PROC MEANS` with both `EPISODE_ID` and `ORGANIZATION_ID` in the `CLASS` statement. Then look at the different levels of `_TYPE_` to see if you could run frequencies on one of them:

```
proc means data = table1 noprint;
    class EPISODE_ID ORGANIZATION_ID;
    var EVENT;
    output out = means sum=TOTAL_EVENT;
run;
```

Comment: I've now tried the proc means and it was such a good idea but still not correct- the _FREQ_ was the increased frequency (and thus incorrect)- the total_event that this created though was pretty close (only an extra 100 or so). Maybe I'll think about this a bit more

Comment: ok- I've gone and added to the means idea using your `code` _Type_ `code` idea. I found out that type 1 was the ones I was looking for and when I subset those ones out using a data step they are correct in the file. The problem comes with this though- the proc means has a column for organization_id but does not include any information in the column and thus it doesn't carry over when I do the data step. Any thoughts why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "any information." What is your datastep after your `PROC MEANS`?

Comment: Sorry- by any information I meant that the organization_id variable has no values in it at all. The values that it should contain (organization #s) aren't there. It's essentially a blank variable after the `PROC MEANS`